# ROS2 callback not called with approximate time synchronizer

Tags: ros2, message-filters

Any idea, why my callback is not called ?

```
#ifndef CONFERENCE_H
#define CONFERENCE_H

#include <camera_info_manager/camera_info_manager.hpp>
#include <image_transport/image_transport.hpp>
#include <memory>
#include <message_filters/subscriber.h>
#include <message_filters/time_synchronizer.h>
#include <onnx/onnxruntime_cxx_api.h>
#include <rclcpp/rclcpp.hpp>
#include <sensor_msgs/msg/camera_info.hpp>
#include <sensor_msgs/msg/image.hpp>
#include <message_filters/sync_policies/approximate_time.h>
#include <array>

typedef message_filters::sync_policies::ApproximateTime<sensor_msgs::msg::Image, sensor_msgs::msg::Image, sensor_msgs::msg::Image, sensor_msgs::msg::Image> approximate_policy;
typedef message_filters::Synchronizer<approximate_policy> approximate_synchronizer;

class ConferenceNode : public rclcpp::Node {
public:
  ConferenceNode();

private:
  message_filters::Subscriber<sensor_msgs::msg::Image> driver_subscriber_;
  message_filters::Subscriber<sensor_msgs::msg::Image> co_driver_subscriber_;
  message_filters::Subscriber<sensor_msgs::msg::Image> passanger_left_subscriber_;
  message_filters::Subscriber<sensor_msgs::msg::Image> passanger_right_subscriber_;

  std::shared_ptr<approximate_synchronizer> my_sync_;


void CameraCallback(
    const sensor_msgs::msg::Image::ConstSharedPtr &driver_msg,
    const sensor_msgs::msg::Image::ConstSharedPtr &co_driver_msg,
    const sensor_msgs::msg::Image::ConstSharedPtr &passanger_left_msg,
    const sensor_msgs::msg::Image::ConstSharedPtr &passanger_right_msg) const;

};

#endif
```

cpp:

````
#include "conference/conference_node.hpp"
#include <cv_bridge/cv_bridge.hpp>
#include <opencv2/highgui.hpp>
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>
#include <vector>

using std::placeholders::_1;
using std::placeholders::_2;
using std::placeholders::_3;
using std::placeholders::_4;

ConferenceNode::ConferenceNode() : Node("conference") {

  driver_subscriber_.subscribe(this, "driver_camera/image", rmw_qos_profile_system_default);
  co_driver_subscriber_.subscribe(this, "co_driver_camera/image", rmw_qos_profile_system_default);
  passanger_left_subscriber_.subscribe(this, "passanger_left_camera/image", rmw_qos_profile_system_default);
  passanger_right_subscriber_.subscribe(this, "passanger_right_camera/image", rmw_qos_profile_system_default);

  my_sync_ = std::make_shared<approximate_synchronizer>(approximate_policy(10),driver_subscriber_ , co_driver_subscriber_, passanger_left_subscriber_, passanger_right_subscriber_);
  my_sync_->getPolicy()->setMaxIntervalDuration(rclcpp::Duration(100,0));
  my_sync_->registerCallback(std::bind(&ConferenceNode::CameraCallback, this, _1, _2, _3, _4));


}

void ConferenceNode::CameraCallback(
    const sensor_msgs::msg::Image::ConstSharedPtr &driver_msg,
    const sensor_msgs::msg::Image::ConstSharedPtr &co_driver_msg,
    const sensor_msgs::msg::Image::ConstSharedPtr &passanger_left_msg,
    const sensor_msgs::msg::Image::ConstSharedPtr &passanger_right_msg) const {

     RCLCPP_INFO(this->get_logger(),
                "I heard and synchronized the following timestamps: %u, %u,%u,%u",
                driver_msg->header.stamp.sec, co_driver_msg->header.stamp.sec, passanger_left_msg->header.stamp.sec, co_driver_msg->header.stamp.sec);

    cv_bridge::CvImagePtr cv_driver_image_const_ptr =
      cv_bridge::toCvCopy(driver_msg, driver_msg->encoding);
    cv_bridge::CvImagePtr cv_co_driver_image_const_ptr =
      cv_bridge::toCvCopy(co_driver_msg, co_driver_msg->encoding);
    cv_bridge::CvImagePtr cv_passanger_left_image_const_ptr =
      cv_bridge::toCvCopy(passanger_left_msg, passanger_left_msg->encoding);
    cv_bridge::CvImagePtr cv_passanger_right_image_const_ptr =
      cv_bridge::toCvCopy(passanger_right_msg, passanger_right_msg->encoding);


  RCLCPP_INFO(this->get_logger(), "I got new image" );
}

```
````

Answer (score 0):

Solved it.
rclcpp::Duration(100,0) was to high;