# Multiple subscriptions in a single callback

Tags: callback, subscribe

I want to do parallel process of multiple subscriptions in a single callback. I have been looking for information, but there is barely any information regarding this in ROS 2 Humble. I found callback groups, but I'm not sure if this addresses my issue. I will provide my current code. I new to ROS 2, so I apologize if this has been solved already.

````
subscription1_ = this->create_subscription<std_msgs::msg::Float32>("/time", 10,
    std::bind(&Process::proc_signal_callback, this, _1, _2));
);
subscription2_ = this->create_subscription<std_msgs::msg::Float32>("/signal", 10,
    std::bind(&Process::proc_signal_callback, this, _1, _2));

void proc_signal_callback(
    const std_msgs::msg::Float32& time,
    const std_msgs::msg::Float32& signal)
{
    RCLCPP_INFO(this->get_logger(), "Time: '%g', Sine: '%g'", time.data, signal.data);
}
```
````

Answer (score 1):

There is no reason two messages will be received exactly at the same time, so when do you expect the function `proc_signal_callback` to be called?

If the two topics are synchronized (e.g. you know the publisher will always publish on `/time` and `/signal` at the same time) then I would use a single message to convey the two values. It can be a `Float32MultiArray` if you do not have any semantic.

If they are not, then the callbacks should just store the message locally (in a member variable) and a timer should call the `proc_signal_callback` at a given frequency, using the last version of the messages (if any).
To reduce delays, the callbacks can set a flag to tell a new message has been received, and the timer can run at a high frequency but check this flag before doing anything fancy.

Answer (score 0):

One approach would be to use a synchronizer from the `message_filters` package. Unfortunately I don't have a good documentation at hand to link to, but maybe you can find some inspiration here:

- [ROS2 callback not called with approximate time synchronizer](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/questions/103824/ros2-callback-not-called-with-approximate-time-synchronizer)

Another simple approach to this, is to have the callbacks save the latest message(s) on each topic, and have one of the handlers (or an independent timer callback) trigger the actual processing in the desired rate. Of course you need to think about what happens in case of latency, missing data or alike. The approximate synchronizer from the message filters would take care of this for you.